# protect_from_forgery vs. Firefox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firefox

I've recently switched from storing session data in a cookie to storing it in the database.

Now every POST request causes an **ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken** error.  It only happens in Firefox, and only on my home machine (I tried it out at work today in the same version of FF and everything was fine).  This leads me to believe that it's something do do with the cookie I deleted yesterday...

Here's the relevant part of environment.rb:

```
# Your secret key for verifying cookie session data integrity.
# If you change this key, all old sessions will become invalid!
# Make sure the secret is at least 30 characters and all random, 
# no regular words or you'll be exposed to dictionary attacks.
config.action_controller.session = {
:session_key => '_basillslam_session',
:secret      => '373ee5b69a4a31d3318485fs368c41fac6b797a1f5c35693b49bd34e8a96291b92dd577bd49de7aeea56c9ffa1af2d8386bafe857220cafacfa0028f01be357d78'
}

# Use the database for sessions instead of the cookie-based default,
# which shouldn't be used to store highly confidential information
# (create the session table with 'rake db:sessions:create')
config.action_controller.session_store = :active_record_store
```

In application.rb:

```
protect_from_forgery :secret => 'f1d54db45b47ec94a6a54b1e744fafa6'
```

Here's the part of the full trace where the error is thrown:

```
C:/INSTAN~1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/request_forgery_protection.rb:79:in `verify_authenticity_token'
C:/INSTAN~1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:469:in `send!'
C:/INSTAN~1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:469:in `call'
C:/INSTAN~1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:441:in `run'
C:/INSTAN~1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:716:in `run_before_filters'
C:/INSTAN~1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:695:in `call_filters'
C:/INSTAN~1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:689:in `perform_action_without_benchmark'
C:/INSTAN~1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_without_rescue'
C:/INSTAN~1/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:293:in `measure'
C:/INSTAN~1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_without_rescue'
C:/INSTAN~1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:199:in `perform_action_without_caching'
C:/INSTAN~1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/caching.rb:678:in `perform_action'
C:/INSTAN~1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:33:in `cache'
C:/INSTAN~1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.0.2/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:8:in `cache'
[etc. ... ]
```

Has anybody experienced this before?  Or does anybody know why this might be happening?

Comment: BTW, it's not a problem since you're not using cookie sessions anymore... but you probably want to make a habit of blocking out that secret key in the future. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact same thing happened to me when I switched one of my sites.  Delete the Rails session cookie for that site in your home Firefox Browser.

It only happens if you had a pre-existing session that used the cookie store. So, hopefully, only you and your browser will ever see the issue.  After you've deleted the cookie, you'll never see the error again.

With the session in the database and only a random key to map to that session in the browsers cookies, the session protection magic is no longer necessary.

Comment: Thanks Otto, I had a feeling it'd be something to do with old cookies.  The thing is though, I'm pretty sure I've deleted all the cookies for this application (the machine has been turned off more than once, which would have cleared sessions, right?).  Is there some specific step I'm missing out?

Comment: Also, is it okay that the :session_key and :secret are being set both in environment.rb and application.rb?  Is this causing confusion perhaps?  I just made sure my cookies are deleted and I'm still getting the same error.  Weird.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments Otto.  I had to resort to re-installing Firefox.  A little annoying that deleting my session cookies wasn't fixing the problem, since that's almost definitely why the error was being thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Otto, I now know the reason why this happens. Although, I was able get around the problem by writing `<%= token_tag %>` within the form which is being POSTed. The `token_tag` puts a hidden field containing the authenticity token in the form and hence the **ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken error** vanishes.

Comment: Thanks, Chirantan, I'll give this a go tonight.  It seems odd that I should have to make a change to the site to make it work on my home machine though!  I'm pretty sure that Rails's form helpers include the necessary authenticity_token by default, right?

Comment: Makes sense, turning off the cookie session store probably makes the form helpers not insert that anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If you have several users on your app it's not easy to make them all deleting cookies.
When you switch to database storage, to prevent session data collision between cookie and database storage you can also change

```
config.action_controller.session[:session_key]
```